# Log of SVN activity for a certain user?

Tags: svn

Is it possible to query for all activity relating to a specific user across all repositories. Including any check out action? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that svn has built-in support for that feature, but you could write a little script to run

```
svn log --xml
```

In the directories of whatever repos you wanted to test, then parse it and pick only the entries done by a given user.

Comment: Where do I do this, in the directory of the repo on the server? E.g. the directory which contains conf, dav, db, format, hooks, locks. If so it says svn: '.' is not a working copy

Comment: No, you'll want to do it on a client. svn co http://url.com/svn/thing; cd thing; svn log --xml

Comment: Then that would not show if another user checked it out? Basically I want to know who is checking out a certain repo.

Comment: @Louis: There is no way to find out who checked out a repository. Everyone who has access to it can check it out as often as they want. All you can see is the changes that have been checked in on the repository.

Comment: Well, if you had it running via Apache, you could parse the logs and see what user names had accessed it - that would be like checking to see who had checked it out.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a little hack which uses GNU's sed to execute a regular expression against the log output from the svn command. Change username to the user name you require

```
svn log | sed -n '/| username |/,/-----$/ p'
```

To get a list of your folders from a webdav config (I was on an Ubuntu box at the time of writing) try something like this....

```
grep SVNPath /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf | grep -v \# | sed 's/^\s*SVNPath //'
```

This simply greps once for the line, twice to remove commented lines and filters the SVNPath keyword and associated white-space characters.  Your results are repo folders so if you are going to use the svn command, prepend with file://

Answer (score 3):

I second [Allyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693173/2693252#2693252), but have one addition: If you're on Windows, TortoiseSVN allows you to filter the output, including the ability to filter by user name.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving here via Google Search and use the `--search` argument to the svn log command.

```
Q:\Projects>svn log --search username
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2874 | username | 2019-03-15 07:37:59 +0000 (Fri, 15 Mar 2019) | 1 line

Test Software
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2873 | username | 2019-03-15 07:36:15 +0000 (Fri, 15 Mar 2019) | 1 line

Latest Document
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also like to use the `-v` argument to see details of the changes

check `svn help log` for more information

Comment: svn: invalid option: --search

Comment: @DannySchoemann which version of svn are you using? For me `svn --version` reports `svn, version 1.14.0 (r1876290)` and is from May 2020. You may need to update your client.